# Is it ok to pass large objects in method parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing a Rails application where people can take quizzes. I have a model `BrowserGame` that's taking care of the controller logic (sessions, redirecting etc.). Currently, this is my `#initialize` method:

```
class BrowserGame
  def initialize(controller)
    @controller = controller
  end
end
```

And in the controller I have a method

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

  # actions

  private

  def browser_game
    BrowserGame.new(self)
  end
end
```

As you can see, I'm passing the whole controller to `BrowserGame#initialize` (so I can manipulate with sessions and others). Is this a good idea? Are there any side effects, since the controller instance is a large object?

Comment: While it's fine to pass large objects, what you're doing (passing the controller into the model) does seem a bit nuts. It's not something I've ever seen done before. Would be interested if you could explain a bit more what you're doing with it?

Comment: I'm implementing a game. So that means keeping score, switching players, saving the game in the database after it finishes. The reason why I called it `BrowserGame` is because it keeps everything in sessions and at the end it saves it to the database (that model is called `Game`). I chose that I have a class that does all that logic (`BrowserGame`). Before I had a module which I included into the controller, but that didn't seem right, because the methods like `#session` didn't exist in the module itself.

Comment: I'm saving the controller in an instance variable, and I defined `#method_missing` to delegate to that controller.

Comment: I kinda got that idea from the "Strong parameters" Railscast, otherwise I would have maybe stayed with the module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is fine to pass large objects as method parameters.  You're not placing the object on the stack, just a pointer to it.  As far as side-effects -- anything you do to `@controller` from within `BrowserGame` is seen through any other reference to the controller, but that's probably what you already expect.

Comment: Yes, that's what I expect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with passing a large object.

As Darshan says, it is only a pointer.

It would be better to only pass serializable objects if you are forking the process/thread or otherwise trying to create a delayed job to run in the background.

Comment: This answer is confusing. The variable is a reference to an object whether you 'read from it' or 'write to it' (although you can change what the variable is a reference to). If you are using threads you may need to synchronize access to the object (with a Mutex) but whether the object is serializealble (isn't everything?) shouldn't matter.

Comment: @pguard Oops, left that in after I deleted further elaboration of it. Was thinking about another language.